# What's the best way to process HTML in Python?

Tags: python, html, bdd, lettuce

I'm trying to write some tests with [Lettuce](http://lettuce.it), started using `lxml` but found kinda complicated to integrate it with `Django` in the same way that Webrat integrates with Rails.

Comment: Did you not have any success with [this](http://lettuce.it/recipes/django-lxml.html#recipes-django-lxml)?

Comment: Yeah, but to be honest is really complicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use beautiful soup with django and no problems.

http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what your problem with lxml being complicated is (parsing html will be complicated!) but I've always used Beautiful Soup for handling html, finding elements, constructing trees etc etc.

Comment: Yeah... I wanted a simpler solution. But I agree is complicated by definition.